# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of string'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm playing about learning VB.NET by making a basic calculator and making the code slowly more complex, started playing with classes and problems and ran into this error (see title) and can't fathom what it means. Here's my code in full:

```
Class Calculator

    Private _num1, _num2, _result As Double
    Private _operation, _output() As String
    Private _ressuc As Boolean = True

    Public Function input() As String()
        Console.Write("Enter your first number: ")
        _num1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Operation? (Add, Subtract, Divide, Multiply, Modulus, Power): ")
        _operation = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Enter your second number: ")
        _num2 = Console.ReadLine()

        _output = calculate(_num1, _num2, _operation)

        Return _output

    End Function

    Private Function calculate(num1 As Integer, num2 As Integer, operation As String) As String
        Dim result As Double = Nothing
        Dim ressuc As Boolean = True

        Select Case operation
            Case "add", "+"
                result = num1 + num2
            Case "subtract", "-"
                result = num1 - num2
            Case "divide", "/"
                result = num1 / num2
            Case "multiply", "*"
                result = num1 * num2
            Case "modulus", "%", "mod"
                result = num1 Mod num2
            Case "power", "^"
                result = num1 ^ num2
            Case Else
                ressuc = False
        End Select

        If ressuc Then
            calculate = ("Your answer is: " & result.ToString())
        Else
            calculate = ("Function '" & operation & "' not available.")
        End If

    End Function

End Class


Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim calc As Calculator = New Calculator()
        Console.WriteLine(calc.input())
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

And the error resides here:

```
_output = calculate(_num1, _num2, _operation)
```

The calculate function (and it's variables) is underlined and displays the error in the title. Can someone explain to me why a string isn't being returned from 'calculate' and how I can fix it?

Comment: What if you change '_output()' to just '_output'?

Comment: @War10ck calculate returns a string. in VB.net you can return a value by assigning the function name a value.

Comment: @War10ck It does.  He has the lines calculate = ("Your answer is: " & result.ToString()) and calculate = ("Function '" & operation & "' not available.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `()` from `output()` in your declaration and from your `String()` return type of the `input` function

```vb
Class Calculator

    Private _num1, _num2, _result As Double
    Private _operation, _output As String
    Private _ressuc As Boolean = True

    Public Function input() As String
        Console.Write("Enter your first number: ")
```

The reason for this is that when you declare a variable ending in `()` or using the `As` keyword and then a type ending in `()`, you are telling it that you want an array of that type. So you can either remove the `()` from  the code or you can leave them there and access all of the items as if they were arrays. since you weren't accessing or using them as arrays, it was far easier to just remove the offending `()`s.

Comment: That solves that error, but moves it to the return, Return _output now has the value of type..... error :/

Comment: I FIXED IT! I took the brackets from the string in "input() as string() " and it works, thanks a lot:)

Comment: Your input is trying to return an array of strings, not just a string.  So change Public Function input() As String() to Public Function input() As String

Comment: wasn't quite fast enough I see. I saw the second set of `()` and I was editing my answer when you posted your comments...

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your variable `_output` as a String *Array*:

`Private _output() As String` which is the same as `Private _output As String()`

Try removing the parenthesis from the declaration as it doesn't look like your program should be using a string array.

`Private _output As String`